# Ecto query with fragment

Tags: jquery, elixir, ecto

I have the following query in my pipeline:

```
where([e], fragment("?->>? = ?", e.fields, ^field_name, ^field_value))
```

`e` in this case stands for `event`. What is the first parameter of the fragment method call doing?

Answer (score 1):

The first parameter of the call to [`Ecto.Query.API.fragment/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.API.html#fragment/1) is the template for the fragment to be send to the database.

Here it is a Postgres function to [retrieve a JSON object field as text](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/functions-json.html). That said,

```
fragment("?->>? = ?", e.fields, ^field_name, ^field_value)
```

is literally “where nested field with a name `field_name` in the JSONB field has a value equal to `field_value`.”